# How to apply maskMoney outside input?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I don't know how to use any mask money outside of the input.

```
 $(function() {
  $('.currency').maskMoney().focus();
 });
```

Works

```
<input type="text" name="amount" class="currency" value="1000000" />
```

Not Works

```
<span class="currency">5000000</span>
```

Comment: Assuming [this project](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) it says *Just a simple way to create masks to your currency form fields with jQuery* - it explicitly says form fields. If you want to format money in javascript in general - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: span isn't an input element, so there's nothing to mask.

Comment: Yeh, right! But is there any other way?
Is there any mask for any tags?